# Can I have a playframework 2.0 webapp and a maven based worker process on heroku?

Tags: maven, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have an existing webapp on heroku that needs to send messages to a queue. I want a worker to pick the messages up and process them. After reading the example on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku I figured running another play process through the Procfile would be wasteful, so I made the following project structure to just use maven for the worker instead:

```
[git root]
   +--[play 2.0 app]
   |  + (project files)
   |  +-Procfile (web)  
   |
   +--[maven based worker]
      + (project files)
      +-Procfile (worker)
```

Now if I try to push all of this to heroku it fails miserably. Heroku thinks this is a play 1.2.4 project and then just falls apart. When I try to specify a play 2.0 buildpack it says "no Cedar-supported app detected". So obviously heroku doesn't like my directory structure.

I want my play app and my maven worker to share the same git repository and if possible, be part of the same deployment to heroku. Is there a common pattern to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix multiple buildpacks in a single app on Heroku.  Instead you could do this all as a Play 2 app.  Here is an example project that will help get you started:
https://github.com/jamesward/play2-scheduled-job-demo

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I was trying to avoid that kind of setup but I guess there is no way around it then.